# How do I programmatically update content in Squarespace?

Tags: git, web, content-management-system, blogs, squarespace

Foreword: i am very very new to Squarespace and also to CMS in general. so please pardon any "dumb" questions

Let's say I own a Squarespace page. Let's say i want to randomly update the home page with a random greetings every day (or every 2 days..etc.) I feel that since this is a CMS, the right way to go is to basically somehow set up a remote server that can scp into my specific Squarespace server instance. the remote server will update some file (or generate some content), and scp the "index.html" file over to the square space instance.

Alternatively, if i have my own server running at home, it looks like i can write some bash scripts to modify (commit & push) and deploy using `git`??

Is this the right idea? what other CMS services provide this?

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is that Squarespace isn't just a CMS - it's a combined hosting/CMS platform that assures you a certain level of uptime, ease of use, and out-of-the-box attractiveness for a limited scope of how much you can access. You'll never touch an HTML file if you opt to customize your template in Developer mode - instead, Squarespace uses `.region` files that let you mix HTML with their JSON templating language.

As for your idea, with Squarespace you have no means of accessing the database - you can only SFTP into your template files or push local changes to git. You'd be better off making a small API (via a different host) that returns a random message when it receives a GET request. In the page you want to display the greeting, make a [code block](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/206543167-Using-the-Code-Block) in the content editor, and write your AJAX call there. Surround it with a div so you can style it however you want.